# word-wrap: break-word not working on span with input and label around

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a `input` with the `type` `radio`. There is an `label` around and a `span` within the `label`. I have a fix `width` on the `span` and I'm trying to break word with `word-wrap: break-word`. It's not working, but I don't know why. If there is **no** `label` element around the `input` and `span`, the same `CSS` rule works. I can't figure out why. I know, I also can just use `input` and `label` without the `span`, but this is the way how I have to do it. Any ideas? Hope it's clear enough.

```css
.form__wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}

.form__label {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.form__input {
  position: relative;
}

.form__text,
.breaking-works {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: calc(600px - 450px);
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="form__wrapper">
  <label class="form__label" for="formLabel">
    <input id="formLabel" class="form__input" type="radio">
    <span class="form__text">I'm a very very very looooooooooooooooooooong text!</span>
  </label>
</div>

<br><br>


<input id="formLabel" class="form__input" type="radio">
<span class="breaking-works">I'm a very very very looooooooooooooooooooong text!</span>
```

Comment: You have `white-space: nowrap` set on the `.form__label`

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb works, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `.form__label` has `white-space: nowrap;` remove that and it will work.

Hope this helps

Comment: I was writing my comment and the "1 new answer" shows up, and I'm like, "He's going to say the same thing as I am!" :):)

Comment: Yep. Need to work on those typing skills \*\*cracking knuckles\*\* :)